# Django how to allow usage of empty ranges in IntegerRangeField

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-filter

I`m using IntegerRangeField (specific field for PostgreSQL) to represent year periods when a bancnote was issued.

Works fine when adding object to db and filtering with non-empty ranges such as 1990-2000, however there are few bancnotes, which were issued during only one year, so the period is for example 2005-2005. When setting range like this, this value becomes as 'None-None' after object adding to db.

Seems like IntegerRangeField doesn`t accept empty ranges.

I was trying to set range like '2005-(no value here)' with blank=True, null=True, this is fine for me, but in this case filters not working for this object.

To be more clear look at the example below:

- 2003-2008: displayed and filtered correctly
- 2003-2003: displayed as 'None-None', filtered wrongly
- 2003-(no value)/(no value)-2003: dislayed as '2003-None'/'None-2003'(satisfactorily for me), filters doesn`t work this

Also was thinking about using DateRangeField, but it provides day and month at the same time as input, what makes a mess. Are there any other possible and correct ways to do this?

Hope I was clear with my situation, looking forward for any advice. Please feel free to ask, I will provide any information. Thanks in advance!

Here is my *models.py*

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import IntegerRangeField
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime


class Bancnote(models.Model):
    Dollar= 'Dollar'
    Euro= 'Euro'

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (Dollar, 'Dollar'),
        (Euro, 'Euro')
    )

    type = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=Dollar)
    par = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    year = IntegerRangeField(null=True, blank=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    sign = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='bons_images')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.par) + ' ' + self.type + ' ' + str(self.year.lower) + '-' + str(self.year.upper)
```

*filters.py*

```
from django import forms
import django_filters

from .models import Bancnote


class BancnoteFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    type = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(name='type', choices=Bancnote.TYPE_CHOICES,
                                       widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'radio'}), empty_label=None)
    par_gt = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='par', lookup_expr='gte', widget=forms.Select)
    par_lt = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='par', lookup_expr='lte', widget=forms.Select)
    year = django_filters.NumericRangeFilter(name='year', lookup_expr='contained_by')

    class Meta:
        model = Bancnote
        fields = ['type', 'par_gt', 'par_lt', 'year']
```

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Bancnote
from .filters import BancnoteFilter


def index(request):
    bons_list = Bancnote.objects.all().order_by('par')
    bons_filter = BancnoteFilter(request.GET, queryset=bons_list)


def image(request):
    bons = Bancnote()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'bons': bons
    })
    return render_to_response('catalogue/bon_detail.html', variables)
```

*index.html*

```
{% extends 'catalogue/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Catalogue{% endblock %}

{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block sidebar %}
    <form method="get">
        <div class="well bs-sidebar" id="style" style="background-color:#fff">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="toggle-menu" onclick="showcontent('#money-type')">Bancnote type
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <div id="money-type">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                        {% for type in filter.form.type %}
                            <li><a href="#">
                                {{ type.tag }}
                                <label for="{{ type.id_for_label }}">{{ type.choice_label }}</label>
                            </a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="toggle-menu" onclick="showcontent('#par')">Bancnote par
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <div id="par">
                    {% render_field filter.form.par_gt id='from' %}{% render_field filter.form.par_lt id='to' %}
                </div>
                <li><a href="#" class="toggle-menu" onclick="showcontent('#period')">Issue years
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a></li>
                <div id="period">
                    <div class="range-input">
                        {% render_field filter.form.year maxlength='4' %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="range-slider">
                        <input value="1917" min="1917" max="2017" step="1" type="range">
                        <input value="2017" min="1917" max="2017" step="1" type="range">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
        </button>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
{# filtering here #}
                {% for bon in filter.qs %}
                    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"4" %}
            </div>
                        <div class="row">
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div style="display: block; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto">
                            <a href="{{ bon.id }}">
                                <img src="{{ bon.image.url }}" style="width: 50%; height: 50%"/>
                                <h5>{{ bon.par }} {{ bon.type }} {{ bon.year.lower}}-{{ bon.year.upper }}</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                        </div>
        </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary issue is that you're not storing ranges correctly. Per the django postgres [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#range-fields),

> All of the range fields translate to [psycopg2 Range objects](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#adapt-range) in python, but also accept tuples as input if no bounds information is necessary. The default is lower bound included, upper bound excluded; that is, `[)`.

In short,

- `tuple(2005, None)` is invalid, because postgres effectively treats an empty bound as infinity. Filtering fails in turn, because infinity exists outside of your bounds check.
- `tuple(2005, 2005)` is invalid, because Django defaults to an excluded upper bound. Postgres normalizes `[2005,2005)` to empty, because the range effectively doesn't exist.
- additionally, your ranges of `tuple(2003, 2008)` are not correct, since 2008 is not included. I'm pretty sure if you filtered for a range of 2008 to 2010, it would be excluded.

To represent a single year, you want to use either:

- `tuple(2005, 2006)`
- `Range(2005, 2005, bounds='[]')` Note that bounds is a string literal ([psycopg2 docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#adapt-range)).

In regards to filtering, the filter performs a `startwsith` and `endswith` check, which I believe is *inclusive*. So, filtering your year by 2005 to 2005 should yield the expected value from the DB. The filter *should* function correctly once the ranges are stored correctly.

Postgres range [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/rangetypes.html) for reference. Section 8.17.5 contains info on boundary behavior and normalization.

Example Range:

```
from psycopg2.extras import NumericRange

NumericRange(2005, 2008, bounds='[]')
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! Sorry for dummy questions, Im pretty new to Django. How and where could I set bounds to '[]'? Somewhere in model I think, but IntegerRangeField doesnt have 'bounds=' attribute. And you was abbsolutely right, filters dont work correctly. By chance, if you know, what is the right way to set lookup_expr like startswitch + endswitch in IntegerRangeFilter if using django-filters?

Comment: No problem. You're not setting the `bounds` on the field - you would be setting it on the `Range` value. It just so happens that [`Range`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.Range) has a default of `bounds='[)'`. As far as the filter goes, it already uses `startswith` and `endswith` ([source](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/1.0.2/django_filters/filters.py#L399-L414)).

Comment: Im sorry again, can`t really figure out where do I need to set this Range value to proper one. Would u be so kind to post an example with my code above?

Comment: Added an example to my answer.

Comment: How could I use Range in my model? IntegerRangeField after adding some object in admin returns me object like "NumericRange(1992, 1997, '[)')" as default. Is it possible to change default behavior of IntegerRangeField for adding bounds like '[)'?

Comment: You would pass a `Range` value to an `IntegerRangeField` field. eg, `some_bancnote.year = Range(2015, 2017, bounds='[]')`. As far as changing the default behavior for the bounds, the docs indicate that the result is always normalized to `[)` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.IntegerRangeField)).

Comment: So the only possible way if I understand correctly, is to set range manually. For example to create additional admin page(cms) for adding bancnotes, where the input values will be passed through Range?

Comment: By the way is there sense to create custom model field which will act like needed

Comment: Not necessarily. Keep in mind that `NumericRange(2015, 2015, bounds='[]')` is equivalent to `NumericRange(2015, 2016, bounds='[)')`.

Comment: Ok, we will see what could be done with this. Thank you for providing so detailed information and patience. Have a good luck!